# Delete indenting spaces one at a time

Tags: indentation, tab-characters

I want to be able to delete indenting spaces one at a time.

If I set `shiftwidth` to 4, it deletes 4 spaces at a time if vim counts them as indentation. Setting `shiftwidth` to 1 fixes the problem, but makes vim autoindents using 1 space instead of a tab and inserts 1 space when I try to insert a tab.

Is it possible to delete spaces counted as indentation one at a time while keeping `shiftwidth` equal to 4?

Comment: This might be helpful: http://vimcasts.org/episodes/tabs-and-spaces/

Answer (score 3):

I think some of your confusion comes down to terminology. There are two separate characters, space `" "` and tab `"\t"`. Tabs are a single character, but get displayed as several blank columns. This can be configured with "shiftwidth". If you do `:set shiftwidth=4` this means

> When I press tab, insert a tab character, and display it as 4 blank columns (or as 4 spaces).

When you hit backspace, it deletes a single tab character that looks like 4 spaces. Now, if you want a tab character to insert 4 *actual space characters*, you should use `expandtab`. If you `:set expandtab`, it means:

> When I press tab, enter *tabstop* spaces instead of a tab character.

So, if you `:set tabstop=4`, the tab key will insert 4 spaces, and backspace will delete one of them at a time. For reference, here are the relevant lines in my `.vimrc`:

```
"Indent settings
set autoindent
set expandtab
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
```

I also have:

```
filetype plugin on
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured out the answer. Set `softtabstop` to 0. Wasn't working with my version of neovim, but it works when tested with original vim.

EDIT: Per [options.txt#softtabstop](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27softtabstop%27) in Vim's help, setting `softtabstop` to 0 disables the `softtabstop` feature. The reason this allows for deleting "tab-like" sequences of spaces in a space-by-space way is presumably because `softtabstop` controls the "number of spaces that a <Tab> counts for while performing editing operations, like…using <BS>," per the manual. It's a bit strange to me in light of this that the [documentation for `tabstop`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27tabstop%27) says that it controls the "number of spaces that a <Tab> counts for," full stop, but I suppose you're meant to infer that `tabstop` is about the file's "appearance," e.g. in normal mode, whereas `softtabstop` is about "editing," e.g. in insert mode. You would be wrong in practice if you did that though, because `tabstop` does control how many spaces you end up inserting in place of a tab if you have `expandtab` on. The whole "appearance vs. reality" thing kind of makes less sense with spaces than it does with tabs, I guess.

To those who doubt the usefulness of doing this, I use it in plaintext files meant for human consumption, because I like to indent things out to arbitrary distances in that context. It works nicely there to set a big `tabstop` like 8, set `softtabstop` to 0, and enable `expandtab`, because you can use the tab key to indent something about as far out as you want and then delete a few spaces to get it just right. I also have `<s-Tab>` (i.e. <Shift>-<Tab>) mapped to 4 spaces if I wanted to add a few spaces instead of delete a few.

Answer (score 1):

Since you actually want indentation to be four spaces, I assume that this is a once-in-a-while thing you want to do.  You could always use `dh` in normal mode.  In the worst case, you'd be typing `dh` three times.  Any more than three and you might as well be pressing the backspace key.  To be a little bit more efficient with these four spaces, you could type `dh`, then start mashing `.` to repeat the deletion.

Given that you're only dealing with four spaces, the math is simple enough to use a count such as `d2h` without needing to think hard about it.  Again, `d2h` is repeatable with `.` so you can delete 2 spaces at a time.

Comment: Wouldn't `x` be better than `dh`? (One less keypress, and deletes the character under the cursor instead of the one to the left.)

Comment: @Rich `dh` is like `<bs>` moving _left_, while `x` is like `<del>` moving _right_. The issue is pressing `<bs>` in insert mode deletes expanded indentation in a leftward direction. Pressing `dh` gets around this in one "action". `x` will work, but is done in two "actions" via `hx` to move in the same direction. The difference is clearer when adding a count: `d2h` vs `2h2x`. What makes the number of actions significant is your ability to use it from insert mode: `<c-o>dh` vs `<c-o>hx`. Given this quality, it could be mapped to keep you in insert mode: `inoremap <m-bs> <c-o>dh`.

Comment: Yeah I've got no idea where I was coming from with that comment. I know that I _wasn't_ suggesting pressing `hx`, but using `x` by itself obviously requires the cursor to be in a different place before you do it.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be pressing x in normal mode. This will delete spaces one by one, no matter what are your settings.